# USMT loadstate script returns error code 71

Tags: powershell, usmt

I am trying to create a loadstate script using resources i have butchered and stuck together. i am pretty rookie at writing code. what i have managed to throw together is below

```
#Get current location
$location = "USMT location"

#Get User and Set Store
$user = Read-Host -Prompt 'NT Username'

$ntuser = "ntuserlocation\" + $user
$store = "statestore" + $user
$root = "C:\programdata\domain\Profile\" + $user
$stickyPath = "C:\programdata\domain\Profile\" + $user + "\StickyNotes"
$photosPath = "C:\programdata\domain\Profile\" + $user + "\Photos"
$taskbar_x64Path = "C:\programdata\domain\Profile\" + $user + "\Taskbar_x64"
$profilePath = "C:\programdata\domain\Profile\" + $user + "\uState"
$emptyProfilePath = "C:\programdata\domain\Profile\_empty"

#Check for User State
if(!(Test-Path -Path $store)){
    Write-Host "No User Store found for" $user
    start-sleep -Seconds 10
    exit
}

#Set Scanstate files
$loadstate = $location + "\amd64\Loadstate.exe"
$migApp = $location + "\amd64\Migapp.xml"
$migUser = $location + "\amd64\Miguser.xml"
$log = $store + "\loadstate.log"

#Capture user state
&$loadstate $store /i:"$migApp" /i:"$migUser" /ue:*\* /ui:$user /nocompress /c /r:3 /l:$log

#Quick Access
$quickAccess = $store + "\QuickAccess\AutomaticDestinations"

#Quick Access
$quickAccessFile = $store + "\QuickAccess\AutomaticDestinations\f01b4d95cf55d32a.automaticDestinations-ms"

if(Test-Path -Path $quickAccessFile){

    $quickAccessDestination = "C:\Users\" + $user + "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent"
    Copy-Item -Path $quickAccess -destination $quickAccessDestination -Recurse -Force
}


#Sticky Notes backup
$stickystore = $store + "\StickyNotes\LocalState"

#Sticky Notes backup
$stickyFile = $store + "\StickyNotes\LocalState\plum.sqlite"

#Photos backup
$photosStore = $store + "\Photos\LocalState"

#Sticky Notes restore path
if((Test-Path -Path $stickyFile) -or (Test-Path -Path $photosStore)){
    
    #Create profile folder
    if(!(Test-Path $profilePath)){
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $profilePath
    }

    #Create empty folder
    if(!(Test-Path $emptyProfilePath)){
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $emptyProfilePath
    }
 
    #Disable inheritance
    $inheritanceAcl = Get-ACL -Path $root
    $inheritanceAcl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $True)
    Set-Acl -Path $root -AclObject $inheritanceAcl

    #remove ACLS's
    $removeacl = Get-ACL $root
    $rules = $removeacl.access
    ForEach($rule in $rules) {
        $removeacl.RemoveAccessRule($rule) | Out-Null
    }
    Set-ACL -Path $root -AclObject $removeacl

    #Set ACL's
    $acl = get-acl -path $root
    $new = $ntuser,”FullControl”,”ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit”,”None”,”Allow”
    $accessRule = new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $new
    $acl.AddAccessRule($accessRule)
    $acl | Set-Acl $root

    $acl = get-acl -path $root
    $new = "SYSTEM”,"FullControl”,”ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit”,”None”,”Allow”
    $accessRule = new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $new
    $acl.AddAccessRule($accessRule)
    $acl | Set-Acl $root

    $acl = get-acl -path $root
    $new = "ADMINISTRATORS",”FullControl”,”ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit”,”None”,”Allow”
    $accessRule = new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $new
    $acl.AddAccessRule($accessRule)
    $acl | Set-Acl $root

    if(Test-Path -Path $stickyFile)
    {
        #Create stickNotes folder
        if(!(Test-Path $stickyPath)){
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $stickyPath
        }

        Copy-Item -Path $stickystore -destination $stickyPath -Recurse -Force
    }

    if(Test-Path -Path $photosStore)
    {
        #Create stickNotes folder
        if(!(Test-Path $photosPath)){
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $photosPath
        }

        Copy-Item -Path $photosStore -destination $photosPath -Recurse -Force
    }
```

after running i get the following

```
LoadState return code: 71

Exception calling "AddAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity references could not be translated."
At line:84 char:5
+     $acl.AddAccessRule($accessRule)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IdentityNotMappedException
```

like i said i am very much a rookie and coding so if there are further mistakes or bits that make no sense please say. i am currently just running this code as a test on 2 laptops one with the test profile and the other a clean install and without the profile

Comment: Is `ntuserlocation` the correct domain for these users?

Comment: yes this is the correct domain

Comment: In PS you do not use new-object with some Net Libraries.  Try : $accessRule = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule]::new($new)